# Only alphanumeric and some other keys work on magic keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, accessibility

My Magic keyboard is acting very weird.  The Caps lock’s light is off and non-functioning. Mainly its alphabet,  numbers, <kbd>⏎ Return</kbd>, <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> work. However,  the <kbd>⇨Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keys don’t work. The right arrow key works, but if I hit the left arrow key, then it produces the following single quote: `'`

Is it botched, mis-configured, or is this some accessibility feature? I already forgot the device (Bluetooth) and re-connected it. That didn’t do anything

It’s just this one magic keyboard. I have another which works fine. I’ve done a reboot. Sticky keys are disabled.

When I use the keyboard viewer. Nothing gets highlighted for the space or backspace keys. Surprisingly when I click on the left arrow key, I got the left arrow and the single quote key highlighted

[image]

I also followed *most* steps from [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8516050) and [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203162) but neither worked for me.

I'm starting to think that this is mainly due to the bashing my little one has done on my keyboard...

Comment: You kinda answered your own question. You have another one that works fine, so the issue is with the keyboard itself, not the Mac. Time to toss that keyboard.

Comment: @SteveChambers I'm not sure. It could be a mis-configuration

Comment: I don't know of any software configuration which could give the results you describe.  Software configurations normally affect all keyboards the same way.

Comment: I also have a keyboard which was physically damaged and now acts strange: some key don't work at all, some keys don't output what I am typing. Since the other keyboard is working fine it sounds like hardware failure of the keyboard. You could easily test that though with another computer or even iPad.

Comment: @X_841 Great idea. I just tried my iPad and unfortunately same problem. It's no longer functional I guess. :(

Answer (score 0):

Likely the keyboard is physically damaged by my child or water damaged. I just tried it with my iPad and same symptoms.

Sounds like a good opportunity to do a keyboard teardown